# SAS Token generated by Set-AzKeyVaultManagedStorageSasDefinition throws Signature did not match errors

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault, sas-token

I am trying to leverage https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.keyvault/set-azkeyvaultmanagedstoragesasdefinition?view=azps-9.2.0 to create a managed sas definition.

The SAS token I use as a template does work, and I am able to validate by querying my blob storage account via the following:

```
https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/lockedcontainer/checkmark.png?{sas-token}
```

When trying to do the same with the SAS token stored in the secret (which is retrieved via the following)

```
Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName {myvault} -Name {myStorageAccount}-SecretName -AsPlainText
```

I receive a Signature did not match error, which from some googling/research seems to be fairly generic.

The secret SAS token was generated to be active for 30 days +, and no key rotation has happened since the secret was generated.

Am I misusing the generated secret sas token?

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the same error like below:***

[image]

I generated the **managed SAS definition** by using below script:

```bash
$sa = Get-AzStorageAccount -Name rukk01 -ResourceGroupName ruk
$kv = Get-AzKeyVault -VaultName 'StorageTestVault'
Add-AzKeyVaultManagedStorageAccount -VaultName $kv.VaultName -AccountName $sa.StorageAccountName -AccountResourceId $sa.Id -ActiveKeyName key1 -RegenerationPeriod ([System.Timespan]::FromDays(180))
$sctx = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $sa.StorageAccountName -Protocol Https -StorageAccountKey Key1
$start = [System.DateTime]::Now.AddDays(-1)
$end = [System.DateTime]::Now.AddMonths(1)
$at = "sv=2018-03-28&ss=bfqt&srt=sco&sp=rw&spr=https"
$sas = Set-AzKeyVaultManagedStorageSasDefinition -AccountName $sa.StorageAccountName -VaultName $kv.VaultName -Name accountsas -TemplateUri $at -SasType 'account' -ValidityPeriod ([System.Timespan]::FromDays(30))
```

[image]

I **retrieved the SAS Token stored in the Key Vault** by using the below command:

```bash
Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName VaultName -Name $sas.Sid.Substring($sas.Sid.LastIndexOf('/')+1) -AsPlainText
```

[image]

I used the above SAS token, and ***I am able to access the Blob successfully*** like below:

```bash
https://StorageAcc.blob.core.windows.net/test.png?sas-token
```

[image]

The error usually occurs if the SAS Token is not matching the resource while requesting on Azure Storage.

Check whether your Azure key Vault is assigned **`Storage Account Key Operator Service Role`** like below:

[image]

**If still the persists**, regenerate the SAS Token and check.